# Disable open up menu on Space/Enter in Xaml

Tags: xaml, c++-cx

I have a bottom menu bar. For unknown reason, when pressing Enter/Space button, the default behavior is that the commands will be fully shown or the first action executed, depending on the state which is extremely undesirable as I am handling the key events for the entire `Page`. I tried setting `IsTabStop="False"` but it does not help. Is there a way to eliminate this baked-in behavior?

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsTabStop="False" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
        <!-- Buttons -->
    </CommandBar>
 </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Where in XAML did you write the BottomBar at the beginning or at the end?

Comment: I made it the first child of `<Page>`.